# nutch content.getContent() can not return entire results

Tags: java, pdf, nutch

I am new to Apache Nutch.

I am using Nutch to crawl some websites to get all web contents (including HTML files, PDF, images).

I have written a small java program to extract Nutch results from SEGEMENTs which looks like :

```
byte[] fileContents = content.getContent();
```

problem here is, `getContent()` returns byte array. Hence if size of PDF content is more than 70KB (approx 70,000 bytes) ; array returned by `getContent()` can not hold entire file contents ans I do not get correct PDFs.

Is there any alternate way to handle large contents

I have read something about `content.read()` / `content.write()` but could not find documentation.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may actually be that Nutch isn't crawling your PDF or is truncating it because of its size. Make sure you have set the `file.content.limit` and `http.content.limit` properties in `nutch-site.xml` to appropriate values. You can set it to `-1` to accept any file size.

Comment: Thanx! These parameters were not properly set for large files. Thanks for solution